# Альтернативные способы очистки экрана консоли

Tags: c, c++

Давно ищу различные способы очистки экрана для консоли. Функция system("cls") крайне неудобная, т.к. привязывает к винде и требует подключения огромнейшего заголовка windows.h Собственная функция по "сдвигу экрана" не удобна, так как долгая и откручивает до середины экрана. Помогите пожалуйста.

P.s.  штучки типа `'\r'` работают только на одну строку(

Comment: Так вроде system тянет stdlib.h а не windows.h

Answer (score 3):

И все таки проще всего через system() и #ifdef-ы

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define CLEAR_SCREEN "cls"
#else
#define CLEAR_SCREEN "clear"
#endif

...
system (CLEAR_SCREEN);
...
```

Comment: Хвататься за платформинку вообще неправильно. Это зависит не от платформы, а от терминала. Конечно, так обстоят дела только если бояться *огромнейших заголовков* ncurses.

Comment: Хитроумно придумано!

Answer (score 1):

## ШИНДОШS

```
#include <windows.h>

void clear_terminal() {
  HANDLE                     hStdOut;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
  DWORD                      count;
  DWORD                      cellCount;
  COORD                      homeCoords = {0, 0};

  hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

  /* Get the number of cells in the current buffer */
  if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi)) return;
  cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

  /* Fill the entire buffer with spaces */
  if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, (TCHAR)' ',
      cellCount, homeCoords, &count))
    return;

  /* Fill the entire buffer with the current colors and attributes */
  if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hStdOut, csbi.wAttributes,
      cellCount, homeCoords, &count))
    return;

  /* Move the cursor home */
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, homeCoords);
}
```

## POSIX

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <term.h>

void clear_terminal() {
  if (!cur_term) {
    int result;
    setupterm(NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, &result);
    if (result <= 0) return;
  }

  putp(tigetstr("clear"));
}
```

Дальше препроцессор в помощь по выбору нужной реализации, чтобы все свелось к

```
#include "clear_terminal.h"

...
clear_terminal();
...
```

Источник: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/.

Comment: Вот только в Ubuntu .... 

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/wa$ gcc -c tclrscr.c
    tclrscr.c:2:18: error: term.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
    tclrscr.c: In function ‘clear_screen’:
    tclrscr.c:5: error: ‘cur_term’ undeclared (first use in this    function)
    tclrscr.c:5: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    tclrscr.c:5: error: for each function it appears in.)
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/wa$ uname -a
    Linux avp-ubu1 2.6.32-41-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 27    22:18:56 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/wa$

Comment: `apt-get install libncurses5-dev`

И про `-lncurses` не забудьте.

Comment: Дальше тоже интересно. Ставлю ncurses. Приписываю после clear_screen() { ... } main()

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/wa$ gcc tclrscr.c -lncurses
    tclrscr.c:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or  ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/wa$ 

И только после изучения term.h и **замены имени !!!** clear_screen() на drdaemon_cls() все собралось и экран очистился.

Как водится в term.h было:

    #define clear_screen                   CUR Strings[5]

Comment: Исправил ошибку, спасибо.